# Why is Integer.parseInt(String str) returns int instead of Integer in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, integer, autoboxing, unboxing

I am asking this question because I have to a situation where I have the following two methods:

```
public T get(Serializable id) and
public T get(int id)
```

I have to use the first method in most scenarios and the second method is already deprecated in our system.

My inputs are String so every time I need to call the
`get(Serializable id)` , I have to pass Integer instead of int, otherwise it will use the second method which is deprecated. i.e I have to call `Integer.parseInt(str)` and then I have to **Box** it to Integer ( i.e `(Integer)Integer.parseInt(str)`) which seems redundant.

Is there a better way to do this and why is the implementation of `Integer.parseInt(str)` return int instead of Integer?

Comment: A small point - you don't "*unbox to Integer*" - you box to `Integer`, and unbox to `int`; wrappers are primitives in a boxed form as they *box* the primitive into an `Object`

Comment: @AndyBrown Thank you. I updated my question.

Comment: Because everybody except you prefers it that way.

Comment: No problem. On a side note when you ask *why* about the behaviour of a java core library feature, the answer is almost always "because thats the way it was built". So, you are usually asking a different hidden question, like "what is the shortest/fastest/most elegant way to do X"  - always try and work out what that question is and you'll get what you want far quicker. The answers to the question I linked to have probably collectively covered most of the points you need.

Comment: If `Integer.parseInt` returned an `Integer`, that would impose boxing overhead on _everyone who ever wanted to parse an integer ever._  Most people don't want a boxed `Integer`, they want an `int`, and the situation you're in where a boxed and unboxed type are treated differently is extremely rare (and you should prevent it whenever possible).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> why is the implementation of Integer.parseInt(str) return int instead of Integer?

Because [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) was designed to return `int` and that is its return type.

> Is there a better way to do this...

If you want to get `Integer` instead of `int` use [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-).